# Does this work to reduce eyes strain? Enlarge the PC monitor with a lens

Tags: optics, lenses, stress-strain, vision, biology

I have an idea to reduce eyes strain, but don't know if it works.

I work by looking at PC monitor all day long and I believe my myopia condition is getting worse and eyes strain occurs are due to looking at the PC screen at close distance for long time everyday. So I come up with an idea that put the screen far away, like 6 meters from my eyes, because I have heard that when someone see things above 6 meters from their eyes then their eyes will be relaxed.

I am used to looking at my 24-inch PC screen at a dinstance of about 60 cm, long hours, everyday. Now I want to put it at a distance of 6 meters. But the problem is that I want the size of texts and photos remain the same, so I have to use a bigger screen, in this case it must be 24*(6/0.6) = 240 inch monitor. I can't afford such a monitor. Also my room is not big enough to put a big screen 6 meters away from my desk.

So I come up with this idea: using a lens to enlarge the screen. Let see my setup:

[image]

I put my real screen against the wall of my room, then I put a 1.5 diop lens 0.6 m away from the screen. Base on my knowledges about lens, I calculate that the virtual image of real screen would be 6 m away from the lens and the size of virtual screen would be 240 inches, all things match the requirements at the begining. So as long as my eyes stay in the hatched region and see through the lens, I will see a 240-inch screen at 6 m far away. Because the virtual screen is at 6 m far away, then my eyes will be relaxed. Does this work? The lens would be in rectangular shape and is nearly big as real screen.

Edit: I am myopic, I am wearing -2 dioptre glasses. These glasses is right glasses matching my myopia, it means with theses glasses I can see things at infinity with a maximum relaxation of my lenses (because the glasses create virtual images of things at infinity, these virtual images are at my furthest distance I can see without glasses). And I would like to wear my glasses in the photo above.

Comment: It seems an interesting idea. However, be careful with what equations you use as thin lenses formula use paraxial approximation, which I don't think that you could use here. But the idea seems to be correct and indeed your eyes would be relaxed as the only thing that affects is where the rays come from, not the position of the object.

Comment: @MarcBarceló 1.5 diops is not so strong, also I would like to use a large lens (21.8-inch rectangular shaped lens). With these parameters, could it be assumed to be thin lens?

Comment: It is not about diops, but about the angle that the rays form with the horizontal, it must be small to use the thin lens formula.  That is because it is derived from the diopter formula.

Comment: A lens needs to be flat to commercially work for a monitor. See [answer for fresnel lens for screens](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68609/optics-for-projecting-oled-screen-dlp-style/68645#68645).

Answer (score 4):

Since you assume that the viewing angle of the virtual 240" screen at 6m is the same as your real 24" screen at 0.6m, what you require is nothing but an awkward description of wanting to wear appropriate glasses, because the purpose of glasses is to shift the focal plane only.

If you would require that the viewing angle should increase (the virtual screen appears bigger than in reality, in order to see details better), this would be equivalent to watching the screen through binoculars/telescope. However, binoculars typically require a substantial amount of glass, making them heavy and inconvenient. I am not familiar enough with optics to know whether PC binoculars can be fabricated at a convenient weight, e.g. with plastic lenses. But this wasn't your question anyway.

So, back to the first option, I would estimate that a normal-sighted person needs glasses with around +1 to +2 dioptres to see a screen that is actually at 0.6m at a virtual distance of infinity. That would allow this person a maximum relaxation of her lenses in the eyes. BTW, I use +1.5 dioptres before the PC, because I am presbyopic (i.e. I have a reduced accomodation width due to age).

Since you are myopic, you are already seeing things at virtual infinity which are actually at a finite distance (which is why you can't see things that are further away, because, colloquially speaking there is nothing further away than infinity). If your infinity-viewing-distance is even at 0.6m, then you would not need to do anything further if you want to relax your eyes, just take of your glasses, if you have any.

But if you are heavily myopic, then you would see infinity already closer than 0.6m (e.g. 0.5m), which would explain why watching your PC screen at 0.6m stresses you (it appears blurry). The appropriate measure would be to buy the right glasses matching your myopia (probably something beyond -2 dioptres?). If you do not want to see the doctor, you could try out cheap glasses from the supermarket (which are remarkably good, but they are scratch sensitive and suffer from reflexes because they usually do not have anti-reflective coating) with different dioptre ratings and see what works best.

Note, that this the opposite of what you are proposing (glasses for hyperopic, > 0 dioptres), because

> ...I have heard that when someone see things above 6 meters from their eyes then their eyes will be relaxed.

this is only true for normal-sighted persons, and not for you if you are myopic! Myopic persons need to look at things much closer to relax their eyes.

Some other things that affect strain on the eyes:

1. if you need to look at things at a very short distance because you are myopic (say you can't help putting your screen at 30 cm), then you will have to turn your eyes much more inward, which strains the respective muscles. I don't know, but possibly this is not corrected by your glasses, although I think it would simply require an additional prismatic part of the glasses.
2. relaxing the eyes all the time might be counterproductive, because the lenses of the eyes and the eyes' vitreous body have no blood vessels. Hence, they have to rely on movement/stretching in order to be properly supplied with nutrients/oxygen (and whatever they need to function biologically) through fluid interchange. So it is healthier for the eyes to strain and relax alternately, something which is difficult if you sit before the PC long hours.

Comment: say my furthest distance I can see without glasses is 0.5m, then if I want to see things at 0.6 m, I need glasses. But which is right glasses? Did you mean I need to wear glasses that put 0.6m far screen at 0.5 m then my eyes would be maximum relaxation when looking at this screen? You are true but with these glasses, I can't see thing further than 0.6 m

Comment: My initial idea is that: I see a 0.6m far screen through a lense to create 6m far virtual screen with my right glasses still put on my eyes. My right glasses now is -2 dioptres, I am myopic. My understaing of right glasses is: The right glasses create virtual images of things at infinity, these virtual images are at my furthest distance I can see WITHOUT glasses)

Comment: I know that : "...I have heard that when someone see things above 6 meters from their eyes then their eyes will be relaxed. " is only true for normal-sighted people. But I wear my right glasses all the time in this idea, so I am considered be normal-sighted person because my glasses corrected my myopia. And now I need to see things above 6 m to maximum relax my eyes

Comment: What I wanted to say is: you possibly do not need to wear your (or any) glasses in order to achieve your goal. Your natural vision already allows you to see things at a finite distance with maximum relaxed eyes. I think this is also basically what Cleonis wants to tell you with his answer ("That is, try wearing contacts/glasses that undercorrect your myopia, such that a little bit of myopia remains"). One thing I am pretty sure of is that you do not want to wear additional lenses atop of your regular glasses, but wear at most a single set of glasses that has the properties you require.

Comment: I understand what Cleonis say so I will assume your opinion is the same as Clenonis's. But  there is a defect in Clenonis's idea, that is you can't keep a constant distance from your eyes to the monitor during work. In Clenonis's idea, if you move your head +/-0.1m then your eyes will accomodate in wide range. In my idea, using a lense would keep the virtual image at a constant distance even my head move much

Comment: Yes, of course you can't, but that is where accomodation takes over. If you have no accomodation anymore (because you are like 120 years old and your eyes' lenses are stiff like diamond, or your natural lenses have been replaced by stiff ones during cataract treatment), then you are in trouble, no question. In any other case, you are left with some minor accomodation, which allows you to stay approximately relaxed with your eyes, even if you move before the screen. That is, unless you are headbanging to AC/DC during your PC work... ;-) If you wanted to compensate this, you would need to...

Comment: ... implement an autofocus lens (as it is known in photography), which will certainly be a pain to wear because it is a heavy, multi-lens arrangement (not to mention the motors to shift the lenses). Remember, if you want to keep the focus plane at a certain location while you move your head, the focus plane effectively moves relative to your head. But this is a pointless discussion because no sane person will move his head enough before the PC so that this will become a relevant effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135555/discussion-between-dat-and-oliver).

Answer (score 2):

About [accomodation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accommodation_(eye)):

To bring nearby objects into focus the eye contracts a ring muscle. That contraction gives the lens of the eye room to contract to a more rounded shape. (Conversely, when that ring muscle relaxes ligaments around the lens pull the lens to a flatter shape.)

I gather you want to give your eyes maximum opportunity to be relaxed. For a person without any myopia that would make it necessary to place the monitor quite far away.

With myopic vision there are other options.

I am myopic, so there is a distance beyond which I cannot see sharp. That largest distance of being able to see sharp is the far end of the accomodation range of my eyesight. That is: at that point my eyes are not accomodating, hence the ring muscle that contracts to facilitate the accomodation is *relaxed*.

So if I want to relax my exes I should not wear my contacts, and place my monitor at the far end where I'm just still able to see sharp. (It so happens that personally I'm so highly myopic that that would be unpractical.)

My recommendation for something to try:
Wear contacts/glasses such that the farthest point that you can see sharp is about, say, a meter away from you, and position the monitor there. That is, try wearing contacts/glasses that *undercorrect* your myopia, such that a little bit of myopia remains.

The idea is to tailor the amount of undercorrection such that your eyes are relaxed when your attention is on the monitor.

As I stated earlier, I'm myopic. In addition: [presbyopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presbyopia) has started for me. Now: at my workplace I have no need for distant vision, and I have found that the following works well for me: at my workplace I wear contacts that *undercorrect* my myopia, such that I don't need reading glasses. In a sense I am taking advantage of my myopia. My myopia gives me the option to undercorrect for it, whereas for someone without myopia using reading glasses is pretty much the only option.

(Of course, when driving a car I wear contacts/glasses that provide full correction.)

Comment: I understand your idea that is "Wear contacts/glasses such that the farthest point that you can see sharp is about, say, a meter away from you, and position the monitor there. That is, try wearing contacts/glasses that undercorrect your myopia, such that a little bit of myopia remains." But I feel uncomfortable wearing glasses undercorrect my myopia because during looking at the screen, I occasionally need to see things at long distance. So I would like to wear my full correction glasses and see a screen at 6 m away.

Comment: another defect about your idea is: when wearing glasses undercorrect myopia and place the monitor a meter away (the farthest point I can see sharp), if I move/fluctuate my head that change the distance from my eyes to the monitor +/- 0.1m (because I need to move my body a bit during work) and keep looking at screen, then I would continuously see sharp and feel relaxed (distance = 1m), not sharp and feel uncomfortable (distance > 1m) , or see sharp but my eyes need to accomodate (distance <1).

Comment: This defect don't match my requirement, that is I need to always see sharp the screen and my eyes is always at maximum relaxation, even my head moving a bit. I try using thin lense formula for the case: I wear a full correction glasses (say -2 dioptres) and see a real screen at 6m away. Then I would see an virtual image of the screen at 0.46m (almost at maximum relaxation, that is 0.5m), if I move my head +/-0.2m, the virtual image is still around at 0.46m (you can try calculating it yourself), so my eyes alway see a sharp screen at 0.46m by constant accomodation intensity.

Comment: actually at the beginning, I thought about your idea, but in reality, my eyes would see sharp and not sharp, accomodate than or less continously if I move my head a bit during work or even sometimes, I need to see things at very far distance. Then I come up with an idea of putting real big screen at 6m away and wearing my full corretion glasses. Then my eyes will be relaxed at constant accomodation intensity even if I move my head or see thing at very far distance.  But this requires a big office room and money to buy such big monitor. So finally, I came up with this idea in my question.